# Decrypt sqlcipher file in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite, sqlcipher

I had successfully encrypt my SQLite file using [zetetic method](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/how-to-encrypt-a-plaintext-sqlite-database-to-use-sqlcipher-and-avoid-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database-errors/868). Using DB Browser for SQLite to open encrypted file, I was able to browse the data after entering the encryption key. Currently, I can't seem to decrypt the encrypted file using the below code:

```
        string password = "secretKey";
        using (SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=c:\\test.db"))
        {
            sqlite_conn.ConnectionString = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder(sqlite_conn.ConnectionString){
                Password = password 
            }.ToString();
            sqlite_conn.Open();

            using (SQLiteCommand cmdCount = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * from fruit", sqlite_conn))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmdCount.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(reader["Type"].ToString());

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Encountered error: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'file is not a database
file is not a database'

Update:

```
public class Model
{
  [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
}
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLiteConnectionString(filename, true, password));
conn.ExecuteScalar<int>(String.Format("PRAGMA cipher_license = '{0}';", licenseKey));
conn.CreateTable<Model>();
```

I was able to create table using above code but how do I select, update, insert new data in with parameterized?

Answer (score 0):

First, immediately after opening your connection I would verify that you are properly including SQLCipher. This can be verified by executing a SQL statement which will return the current SQLCipher library version number:

```
PRAGMA cipher_version;
```

If you do not receive a value back from the above query, SQLCipher is not properly integrated with your application.

If you do get a version string value, but remain unable to query the database content itself, either your password is incorrect, or possibly the encrypted database file may have been created with a different major version of SQLCipher than the library version. If this is the case, you can choose to either perform a one-time migration by executing the following command:

```
PRAGMA cipher_migrate;
```

Alternatively, you can choose to set a compatibility mode based on the SQLCipher version that was used to create the database file. More information about the compatibility mode can be found [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#cipher_compatibility).